# How to get checkbox ticked on gridview based on Sharepoint list? ASP.NET, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, spmetal

Im trying to get checkbox ticked based on Sharepoint data. Example, A = true, B = true, C = false. How I'm going to make checkbox ticked on A and B? I want display the checkbox in gridview on page loaded. It is possible to bind the checkbox with the object list? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
   ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// Assume the web has a list named "Announcements". 
  List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

// This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll" 
// so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in. 
  CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100); 
  ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(query); 

  // Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
  context.Load(items); 
  context.ExecuteQuery(); 
  foreach (ListItem listItem in items) 
  { 
    // We have all the list item data. For example, Title. 
    if (yourListItem["CheckBoxFieldName"].ToString() == "A")
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = true;
        }
   else if (yourListItem["CheckBoxFieldName"].ToString() == "B")
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = true;
        }
   else if (yourListItem["CheckBoxFieldName"].ToString() == "C")
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
        } 
  }
```